# Docker containers using more CPU if left online

Tags: docker

I have a web project running using multiple docker containers (using docker for mac). When I start the project, these are the resources stats of the containers (which I collected using `docker ps -q | xargs docker stats --no-stream`):

```
CONTAINER ID        NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
be517fc9aa09        sms_web             1.31%               30.51MiB / 1.952GiB   1.53%               3.58kB / 6.49kB     38.2MB / 1.53MB     35
76a1ec37db51        sms_exp             1.44%               32.23MiB / 1.952GiB   1.61%               5.14kB / 1.81kB     58.8MB / 1.03MB     35
237fc55e2f49        sms_batch           1.19%               34.46MiB / 1.952GiB   1.72%               236kB / 198kB       15.9MB / 0B         6
6049ffd0d25a        sms_models          1.28%               28.96MiB / 1.952GiB   1.45%               44.5kB / 33.2kB     35.8MB / 36.9kB     23
3e2fcdc18e9b        sms_mysql-cl        0.00%               2.113MiB / 1.952GiB   0.11%               8.03kB / 3.1kB      11.9MB / 0B         2
75afa399f2d8        sms_kafka           4.11%               280.7MiB / 1.952GiB   14.05%              196kB / 228kB       185MB / 7.01MB      86
757fd6b1ba98        sms_es              0.96%               1.083GiB / 1.952GiB   55.50%              9.02kB / 7.94kB     345MB / 8.12MB      53
ffb2b1901ea0        sms_mysql           1.10%               81.41MiB / 1.952GiB   4.07%               38.2kB / 48.3kB     95MB / 1.02MB       40
```

After leaving the project running for multiple hours, the CPU resource usage goes way up for almost all the containers:

```
CONTAINER ID        NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
be517fc9aa09        sms_web             18.61%              27.57MiB / 1.952GiB   1.38%               95.3kB / 250kB      20.9GB / 1.58MB     35
76a1ec37db51        sms_exp             21.79%              33.94MiB / 1.952GiB   1.70%               142kB / 109kB       23.1GB / 1.08MB     35
237fc55e2f49        sms_batch           28.67%              32.71MiB / 1.952GiB   1.64%               13.2MB / 11.2MB     54.3GB / 28.7kB     6
6049ffd0d25a        sms_models          20.71%              27.89MiB / 1.952GiB   1.40%               210kB / 189kB       19.8GB / 61.4kB     35
3e2fcdc18e9b        sms_mysql-cl        0.00%               1.711MiB / 1.952GiB   0.09%               9.02kB / 3.32kB     11.9MB / 0B         2
75afa399f2d8        sms_kafka           36.66%              496.1MiB / 1.952GiB   24.82%              10.5MB / 12.2MB     77.7GB / 16.6MB     86
757fd6b1ba98        sms_es              38.05%              1.061GiB / 1.952GiB   54.34%              806kB / 1.05MB      101GB / 30.6MB      66
ffb2b1901ea0        sms_mysql           17.37%              75.31MiB / 1.952GiB   3.77%               150kB / 181kB       38GB / 1.04MB       41
```

The website was not accessed or changed during this time. Why does the CPU usage go up, and is there a way to fix it, or is this a specific issue with my setup?